# Move imaginary decision boundary in sklearn RandomForestClassifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm using RandomForestClassifier for my task. Fitted data (data is balanced), did cross-validation. Of course got some error in prediction, but it's acceptable. My task is binary, but incorrect sample definition as first class is much more critical than second. Are there any ways to move imaginary decision boundary towards the second class to minimize the error for the first class by sacrificing accuracy for the second?

```
    ml_model = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=17, n_jobs=-1, class_weight='balanced')
    ml_params = {'max_depth': range(5, 16), 'max_features': range(4, 15)}

    skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=17)
    ml_grid = GridSearchCV(ml_model, ml_params, cv=skf, n_jobs=-1, scoring='roc_auc')
    ml_grid.fit(x_train, y_train)

...
    ml_grid.best_estimator_.predict(some_sample)
```

Comment: You seem to be looking for the `class_weight` parameter. Play around with it and see how your class errors change.

Comment: You can also try changing the `scoring`  param of `GridSearchCV` to recall or precision of the class you want to be treated as important.

Comment: @FatihAkici I've tried my model with different class_weight parameters, but looks like that gives no affect to result. And I'm not alone: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/326125/class-weight-parameter-in-random-forest-in-sklearn

Comment: @FatihAkici Several experiments showed that `class_weight` works, not effectively, but anyway. Maybe it's because this parameter goal is to serve unbalanced training data... Please format your comment as anwer - I'll submit it

Comment: @VivekKumar And that's works too, but I don't know which anwer to submit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the continuous probability, then you can shift the desicion threshold in order to favor one class over the other. You would then use `estimator.predict_proba() < 0.3` or `< 0.7` instead of `estimator.predict()`.

You can do this with RandomForest, but you might have better result with Gradient Boosted Trees which directly give a continuous output.

You can use the ROC curve plot to determine a suitable threshold to give a precision/recall curve that suits your application.